# RegEx for replacing the middle letter

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Invalid regular expression: Invalid group

I tried except ( ) , fixed and changed . to $ 
but does not work

```
var name = 'ABC'
var pattern = /(?<=.{1})./
return name.replace(pattern, " * ")
```

I want to replace like 'A*C'

Invalid regular expression: Invalid group

Comment: which browser you're using ? some browsers still don't have support for negative lookback, can you add some more example input and out and rules when you want to replace a character

Comment: @CodeManiac I using chrome & safari but doesn`t working in safari only.

Comment: it is not supported in safari till now see the [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @CodeManiac 
this is an error Message some more
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: nothing to repeat
the code is only like that

Comment: @CodeManiac I see.. safari is not supported. thanks 
how to fix it? could you help please?

Comment: What can your input contain? Newlines?

Comment: @jaykim can you add some more example input and out and rules when you want to replace a character ? without proper information one can't help mate

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern uses a lookbehind which has limit browser support.

If the lookbehind is supported, the pattern (which can be shortened to `(?<=.).` will match any char if what is on the left is any char.

That will match `B` in ABC but also in ABCD so is does not matches the middle char.

Another option could be to use:

```
^(.).(?=.$)
```

In the replacement use (without leading and trailing spaces):

```
$1*
```

**Note** that the dot `.` matches any char except a newline so it will also match a space. If you don't want to match a space you could use `\S` instead.

```js
var name = 'ABC';
var pattern = /^(.).(?=.$)/;
console.log(name.replace(pattern, "$1*"));
```

You might replace the middle char without a regex:

```js
let strings = [
  "A",
  "AB",
  "ABC",
  "ABCD",
  "ABCDE",
  "ABCDEF",
  "ABCDEFG",
  "ABCDEFGH",
  "ABCDEFGHI"
].reduce(function(a, c) {
  if (c.length % 2 === 1) {
    let evenHalf = (c.length - 1) / 2;
    a.push(c.substr(0, evenHalf) + '*' + c.substr(evenHalf + 1));
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(strings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we might just want to use start and end anchors and write a simple expression such as:

```
^([A-Z]).([A-Z])$
```

make a replacement with:

```
$1*$2
```

```js
const regex = /^([A-Z]).([A-Z])$/gm;
const str = `ABC`;
const subst = `$1*$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xn1PtK/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Xn1PtK/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For 'ABC' to become A * C or CDE to become C * E, you can just used substr.. :)

```js
function run(){
  var s = "ABC";
  var index = 1;
  s = s.substr(0, index) + ' * ' + s.substr(index + 1);
  alert(s);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="run()">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution with capturing group:

```
var name = 'ABC';
var pattern = /(.)./;
return name.replace(pattern, "$1 * ")
```

What you match with first parentheses is available in the replacement argument through `$1`.

Quick test:

```js
var name = 'ABC'
var pattern = /(.)./
console.log(name.replace(pattern, "$1 * "))
```